# TabLayout indicator hangs between tabs and content vanishes

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tablayout, android-navigationview

My app has an `activity` with `NavigationView` and for different items in the navigation drawer UI is changed by changing the `fragment`. One such fragment has `TabLayout` implemented in it.

When the app starts the `fragment` with `TabLayout` is loaded and it works fine but when I switch between different items in the `navigation drawer` and then come back to the item which has the `TabLayout`, now on swiping the tabs the indicator gets stuck in between tabs and the content on one tab is not even displayed. I have no clue regarding what mistake I might have did. I am using

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.1'
```

This is the activity which has the NavigationView (**activity_start.xml)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_start"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_start"
        app:menu="@menu/start_menu" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

This is the code for app_bar_start.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.optimilia.readaloud.Start">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        app:elevation="0dp">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

This is the fragment which has the TabLayout (**fragment_home.xml**)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/activity_home"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.optimilia.readaloud.HomeFragment">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/custom_tab_layout_height"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabGravity="fill"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"  />

</LinearLayout>
```

**Start.java**

```
public class Start extends AppCompatActivity {

    private NavigationView navigationView;
    private DrawerLayout drawer;
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private Fragment homeFragment = null;

    // index to identify current nav menu item
    public static int navItemIndex = 0;

    // tags used to attach the fragments
    private static final String TAG_HOME = "Home";
    private static final String TAG_STORE = "Store";
    private static final String TAG_ABOUT = "About";
    private static final String TAG_SETTINGS = "Settings";
    private static final String TAG_HELP = "Help";

    public static String CURRENT_TAG = TAG_HOME;

    // toolbar titles respected to selected nav menu item
    private String[] activityTitles;

    private Handler mHandler;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_start);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        mHandler = new Handler(this.getMainLooper());

        drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        // load toolbar titles from string resources
        activityTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_item_activity_titles);

        // initializing navigation menu
        setUpNavigationView();

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            navItemIndex = 0;
            CURRENT_TAG = TAG_HOME;
            loadFragment(true);
        }
    }

    private void loadFragment(boolean selectNavMenu) {

        if (selectNavMenu) {
            selectNavMenu();
        }

        // set toolbar title
        setToolbarTitle();

        // if user select the current navigation menu again, don't do anything
        // just close the navigation drawer
        if (getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(CURRENT_TAG) != null) {
            drawer.closeDrawers();
            return;
        }

        // Sometimes, when fragment has huge data, screen seems hanging
        // when switching between navigation menus
        // So using runnable, the fragment is loaded with cross fade effect
        Runnable mPendingRunnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // update the main content by replacing fragments
                Fragment fragment = getFragment();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame, fragment, CURRENT_TAG);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
            }
        };

        // If mPendingRunnable is not null, then add to the message queue
        if (mPendingRunnable != null) {
            mHandler.post(mPendingRunnable);
        }

        drawer.closeDrawers();
        invalidateOptionsMenu();
    }

    private Fragment getFragment() {
        switch (navItemIndex) {
            case 0:
                if (homeFragment == null) {
                    homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
                }
                return homeFragment;
            case 1:
                SettingsFragment settingsFragment = new SettingsFragment();
                return settingsFragment;
//            case 2:
//                // movies fragment
//                MoviesFragment moviesFragment = new MoviesFragment();
//                return moviesFragment;
//            case 3:
//                // notifications fragment
//                NotificationsFragment notificationsFragment = new NotificationsFragment();
//                return notificationsFragment;
//
//            case 4:
//                // settings fragment
//                SettingsFragment settingsFragment = new SettingsFragment();
//                return settingsFragment;
            default:
                return new HomeFragment();
        }
    }

    private void setToolbarTitle() {
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(activityTitles[navItemIndex]);
    }

    private void selectNavMenu() {
        try {
            navigationView.getMenu().getItem(navItemIndex).setChecked(true);
        }
        catch (Exception ex){}
    }

    private void setUpNavigationView() {
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

            // This method will trigger on item Click of navigation menu
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {

                //Check to see which item was being clicked and perform appropriate action
                switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                    //Replacing the main content with ContentFragment Which is our Inbox View;
                    case R.id.nav_home:
                        navItemIndex = 0;
                        CURRENT_TAG = TAG_HOME;
                        break;
                    case R.id.nav_settings:
                        navItemIndex = 1;
                        CURRENT_TAG = TAG_SETTINGS;
                        break;
                    case R.id.nav_store:
                        navItemIndex = 2;
                        CURRENT_TAG = TAG_STORE;
                        break;
                    case R.id.nav_help:
                        navItemIndex = 3;
                        CURRENT_TAG = TAG_HELP;
                        break;
                    case R.id.nav_about:
                        navItemIndex = 4;
                        CURRENT_TAG = TAG_ABOUT;
                        break;
                    default:
                        navItemIndex = 0;
                }

                //Checking if the item is in checked state or not, if not make it in checked state
                if (menuItem.isChecked()) {
                    menuItem.setChecked(false);
                } else {
                    menuItem.setChecked(true);
                }
                menuItem.setChecked(true);
                loadFragment(false);
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawers();
            return;
        }
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

**HomeFragment.java**

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    private View currView;
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private int[] tabIcons = {
            R.drawable.ic_start,
            R.drawable.ic_recent,
            R.drawable.ic_reading_list
    };

    public HomeFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        currView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) currView.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) currView.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        setupTabIcons();

        return currView;
    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        HomeFragment.ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new HomeFragment.ViewPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new StartFragment(), "Start");
        adapter.addFragment(new RecentFragment(), "Recent");
        adapter.addFragment(new ReadingListFragment(), "Reading list");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    private void setupTabIcons() {
        tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(tabIcons[0]);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(tabIcons[1]);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(tabIcons[2]);
    }

    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I had similar kind of problem, I did a lot of debugging but nothing seemed to work, fragments were sometimes showing no content at all, but it was fixed automatically somehow when the libraries were updated. So I suggest you use the latest libraries for fragment. And also start using commitNow() rather than commit() if you are not backtracking the fragments. It is meant to work best with all the fragment and nested fragment stuff.

Comment: @SamvidMistryI updated the libraries to API level 25 but still face the same problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In `HomeFragment.java` was using `getFragmentManager()` for `ViewPagerAdapter` and this was causing the problem. On switching to `getChildFragmentManager()` it started working perfectly.

Comment: My app stuck when i try getChildFragmentManger()